# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\cot\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What tools would we like to use here? Is there any easy way to establish the limit?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}\,\cot\left(1 \over k\right)$$

Thanks!

Sis!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series diverges. Let $a_k = \dfrac 1{k^2} \cot \dfrac 1k$ and $b_k = \dfrac1k$.

Then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \dfrac{a_k}{b_k} = 1$, so your series diverges by the limit comparison test (since $a_k \ge 0$).

Comment: It seems the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since  $\displaystyle\cot{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{\cos\frac{1}{x}}{\sin \frac{1}{x}}$ and $\cos\frac{1}{x}\sim_{+\infty}1$, $\sin\frac{1}{x}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}$ then 
$$\frac{1}{k^2}\cot{\frac{1}{k}}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}.$$
So the serie with positive terms $\displaystyle\sum_k \frac{1}{k^2}\cot{\frac{1}{k}}$ is divergent by comparaison with harmonic series.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)